# Enable programmatic concurrency on Jetty with WorkManager

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, workmanagers, commonj

I managed to configure a custom implementation of the CommonJ − JSR 237 Timer & WorkManager API (http://commonj.myfoo.de) as a `JNDI` resource on Jetty 6 and 8, but it only works in a global scope.
With this solution `JNDI` name of the resource is `wm/WorkManager`, I need it to be `java:comp/env/wm/WorkManager`, but due to restrictions, I cannot use `java:comp/env` in a global JNDI name because it's reserved to application scoped resources.
I've created a new configuration file called `{jetty.home}/etc/jetty-wtm.xml` and added to `{jetty.home}/start.ini`.
Here is `jetty-wtm.xml`content for Jetty 6, for greater versions it's a bit different, but works too:

```
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure Server Time and Work Managers                         -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">


    <New id="WorkManager" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>wm/WorkManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManager">
                <Arg>
                    <New id="threadPool" class="de.myfoo.commonj.util.ThreadPool">
                        <Arg type="int">0</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">10</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">2</Arg>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>

    <New id="TimeManager" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>tm/TimeManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="de.myfoo.commonj.timers.FooTimerManager">
                <Arg>
                    <New id="threadPool" class="de.myfoo.commonj.util.ThreadPool">
                        <Arg type="int">0</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">10</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">2</Arg>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

I need to mantain standard JNDI naming `java:comp/env/{RESOURCE}` specifically `java:comp/env/wm/MyWorkManager`across servers, but standard `WEB-INF\jetty-env.xml` configuration file doesn't work.
Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I've tested the `jetty-env.xml` local configuration file in Jetty 9 and it works as expected. It seems in versions under 9 `JNDI` it's not fully supported. Here is the configuration file contents:

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<New id="WorkManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg><Ref id="wac"/></Arg>
        <Arg>wm/MyWorkManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManager">
                <Arg>
                    <New id="threadPool" class="de.myfoo.commonj.util.ThreadPool">
                        <Arg type="int">0</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">10</Arg>
                        <Arg type="int">2</Arg>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Hi @Rafael, do you know any work manager implementation i.e. FooWorkManager class implementation?? Thanks.

Comment: @RIPAN we've created our own, you can start at http://commonj.myfoo.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI#Setting_JNDI_Entries_as_Global_or_Scoped),

> Sometimes it is useful to pass configuration information to a web app at runtime that you either cannot or cannot conveniently code into
>   a web.xml . In such cases, you can use
>   org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry, and even override an entry of
>   the same name in web.xml.
>
> ```
> <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
>   <Arg></Arg>
>   <Arg>mySpecialValue</Arg>
>   <Arg type="java.lang.Integer">4000</Arg>
>   <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
> </New>
> ```
>
> > This example defines a virtual env-entry called mySpecialValue with
> >     value 4000 that is unique within the whole JVM. It is put into JNDI at
> >     java:comp/env/mySpecialValue for *every* web app deployed. Moreover,
> >     the boolean argument indicates that this value overrides an env-entry
> >     of the same name in web.xml. If you don't want to override, then omit
> >     this argument, or set it to false.

For Resource in custom files inside `etc`, the documentation states that

> Assume the following naming entry is in
>   `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty-myjndi.xml`:
>
> ```
>  <New  id="jdbc/myds"  class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
>      <Arg></Arg>
>      <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
>      <Arg>
>        <New  class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
>          <Set  name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chat</Set>
>          <Set  name="User">root</Set>
>          <Set  name="Password">sillyness</Set>
>        </New>
>      </Arg>
>   </New>
> ```
>
> Then you can link `jdbc/myds` into your webapp's namespace as
>   `java:comp/env/jdbc/myfoo` by using a `WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` file:
>
> ```
>    <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.NamingEntryUtil" name="bindToENC">
>        <Arg></Arg>    <!-- scope of naming entry, ie same as first argument to your naming entry definition, in this case, null -->
>        <Arg>jdbc/myfoo</Arg>
>        <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
>    </Call>
> ```
>
> Note that you *must* use a WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml file to call the
>   "bindToENC" method and *not* a context xml file, as the latter is not
>   interpreted at the correct phase of the webapp's deployment to have
>   the java:comp/env namespace created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `env-entries` are not working for commonj, with `java.lang.*` and `java.naming.Reference/Referenceable` works as expected, but "custom POJOS" doesn't work for me even in Jetty 9.

Comment: @Rafeal Gullien Okay, try the bindtoENC method in the Resource class, You can bind it with a custom name,. Check download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs, you'd have to check in jetty.plus.jndi -> `Resource`, modified answer as well.